# Sphinx empty index

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to create index from table **domains**. When I get 10 attributes, everything is ok. When i add 11-th, indexer returns:

```
collected 1629494 docs, 0.0 MB
```

Config:

```
#...
sql_attr_uint       = did
sql_attr_string     = url
sql_attr_uint       = zone_id
sql_attr_uint       = first_letter
sql_attr_uint       = category_id
sql_attr_uint       = is_parking
#sql_attr_uint      = data3
sql_attr_uint       = views
sql_attr_uint       = data1
sql_attr_uint       = data2
sql_attr_uint       = is_top_site
#...
```

When I remove any of the 11 attributes, everything works fine. Is there some kind of limit ?

Comment: I beleive there is a limit of 2Gb (or maybe 4Gb) on the main attributes file. (I know string attributes is 4Gb). How big is your data you indexing? What size do the index files come to when it works?

Comment: data size is 2-5MB. very small

Comment: really? 5Mb / 1.6M gives 3.2 bytes per document. Thats amazing! How do you fit 10 seperate attributes in 3.2 bytes?

Comment: indexing index 'domains'...
collected 1639352 docs, 1.6 MB
sorted 1.6 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1639352 docs, 1639352 bytes
total 11.930 sec, 137410 bytes/sec, 137410.69 docs/sec

Comment: Thats the size of the 'full-text' the raw text that makes up the word-index. Wanting the size of the attributes. Trying to find out if you hitting a size limit. Do a "ls -l /var/sphinx/index.s*" (obviouslly using your path to your index) - **when the index is succcessfully built** and see what the sizes of the files are.